# Profiling Django: very slow performance

Tags: python, django, performance

I developed a Django application and adding some data through the admin interface. The performance is totally abysmal at this point and this never happened to me so far.

It is slow locally (latest version Macbook pro) and remotely (Webfaction custom Django install). Remotely it even regularly drops requests when simply retrieving records through the admin.

I am new to profiling, but I installed the Django-Debug-Toolbar. It shows that a record takes over 15000 ms to retrieve in the admin and the SQL queries take 600 ms with over 1,100 queries performed. Remotely the app does not push the server memory to the limit (300 MB of 512, with another app running).

It looks like there is no way that 1,100 queries are needed. Would you agree that this is the bottleneck? Does it fully explain the performance: 600 ms for the queries vs 15000 ms total request time?

Some characteristics of my project:

- Nothing fancy, mostly vanilla Django stuff
- Added a Django-Rest-Framework interface
- Postgres database with 52 tables
- No huge amount of data, biggest tables hold 10,000 records
- Does seem to slow down with more data added.
- No 'strange' or superfluous relationships between the models. t least that I am aware.

Besides the question that I just asked: what and how should I be looking for to fix this? Common mistakes?

Comment: Yes, the queries are almost certainly to blame. You're already using the debug toolbar: does it show any repeated or similar queries? That's usually a sign that things can be optimised.

Comment: Yes definitely, looking into that now. The first few queries make sense and last few as well. The 1000 queries in between are repetitions with different ID's and do not seem to be needed at all. Not sure why my models invoke them. Digging into it now.

Comment: Once place to look is in the models' `__unicode__` methods: if those are looking up data across relationships that could be the culprit. You might be able to fix this by setting the modeladmin [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) attribute appropriately.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for that pointer. I do have some `__str__` and `get_..` methods in there. Eliminating them one by one now. No luck so far.

Comment: Ok, how to fix this is easy enough. The debug toolbar graciously gives you the exact line of code in the models which is to blame. Down to 13 queries now. Yet have to find out *why* something was wrong... A simple `__str__` method that call a one-to-one relationship, which in turn calls a foreign key. Looks like 2 queries to me, rather than 500. Maybe due to some denormalization?

Comment: But that's 2 queries for every model you show on the page, so if you're showing a list of 100 models, that's 200 queries, and so on. Again, select_related is your friend here. You might also be interested in a [talk](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/07/25/europython-2010-talk-advanced-django-orm-technique/) I gave on this very subject a few years ago.

Comment: Not the case here, just querying a single record. Will check out your talk. Are you confident it is still up-to-date (being 4 years old)?

Comment: Not totally confident, but it might give you some pointers. Although if this is the admin edit page rather than the list page, then it's probably happening in a select box for a relationship field; in this case [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering here to avoid further discussion.

The culprit has been the same in multiple places. I have followed this pattern (Python 3):

```
class RootFoo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Foo(models.Model):
    rootfoo = models.ForeignKey(RootFoo)
    spam = models.ForeignKey(Spam)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rootfoo.__str__()


class SpecificFoo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
    property = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the admin overview for SpecificFoo it lists 100 instances through a single query. When you open an instance of SpecificFoo however, it must populate the select-box for the `foo` foreign key and does so by executing the queries for every individual Foo item. Slow.

As pointed out by @DanielRoseman: the raw_id_field might be a way around this. Somehow I feel that there should be a way to tell Django to populate the `foo` select field with the results of a single query to list all items...

Small update: I have come to accept that there is no easy way around this, other than using the `raw_id_fields`.